# NPC Knight ability "parry" - how often can it be used?

Tags: dnd-5e, reactions

In the Monster Manual the Knight has a reaction ability called Parry:

> **Parry.** The knight adds 2 to its AC against one melee attack that would hit it. To do so, the knight must see the attacker and be wielding a melee weapon.

I'm not clear on how often this can be used - it says "against one melee attack that would hit it" is this once per turn or just against any melee attacks?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The knight's parry ability uses its *reaction* therefore it follows the usual *reaction* rules found on page 190 of the PHB:

> [...] When you take a reaction, you can't take another one until the start of your next turn.